# Using DataList to display search results

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datalist

I'm using datalist to display search results, for example i'm retrieving this sample of fields
[image]

I'm retrieving the name and description using `Text='<%# Eval("field") %>'`in their corresponding labels, and retrieving the category and the user using code behind like this

```
Dim CategoryLabel As Label = DirectCast(DataList1.Items(0).FindControl("CategoryLabel"), Label)
CategoryLabel.Text = DirectCast(dt2.Rows(0)(0), String)
Dim UserLabel As Label = DirectCast(DataList1.Items(0).FindControl("UserLabel"), Label)
UserLabel.Text = DirectCast(dt2.Rows(0)(1), String)
```

This work fine for the first item only as you see, but the rest of the item shows blanks.
The reason am using this approach that i'm storing the values of user and categories as foreign keys (ID'S) to different tables other than the one i bind the datalist to it, and i want to display texts instead of the id numbers in the search results. How can i make those two labels (category and user) get populated in similar way like the ones with the `Eval`.

P.S. All the four labels are in one  `<ItemTemplate>`

The Full Code

```
  If (con.State = ConnectionState.Closed) Then
        con.Open()
    End If
    Dim command As SqlDataAdapter
    command = New SqlDataAdapter("select * FROM Lostitem WHERE city=@city AND datelost=@datelost AND (name Like '%' + @name + '%' OR name Like '%' + '""' + '%') ", con)
    Dim ide2 As Integer = ddlCities.SelectedValue
    command.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", ide2)
    command.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@datelost", TextBox1.Text)
    command.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox2.Text)
    Dim DetailsAdapter2 As SqlDataAdapter

    Dim dt1 As New DataTable

    command.Fill(dt1)
    DataList1.DataSource = dt1
    DataList1.DataBind()
    Dim rowcount As Integer = dt1.Rows.Count
    Dim idd As Integer
    For row = 0 To rowcount - 1
        idd = dt1.Rows(row)(0)



        DetailsAdapter2 = New SqlDataAdapter(" select Category.subcategory, Users.username from [Category]  JOIN [LostItem] ON (Category.CategoryID = LostItem.CategoryID) JOIN [Users] ON (LostItem.[User] = Users.[userid] ) WHERE (LostItem.LostId=" & idd & "    ) ", con)
        Dim dt2 As New DataTable

        DetailsAdapter2.Fill(dt2)
        Dim CategoryLabel As Label = DirectCast(DataList1.Items(0).FindControl("CategoryLabel"), Label)
        CategoryLabel.Text = DirectCast(dt2.Rows(0)(0), String)
        Dim UserLabel As Label = DirectCast(DataList1.Items(0).FindControl("UserLabel"), Label)
        UserLabel.Text = DirectCast(dt2.Rows(0)(1), String)

    Next
    con.Close()
    ResultPanel.Style.Add("display", "block")
```

Comment: Are you getting all values in the dt2? Can you pls post the full code?

Comment: @AA i just realized that i don't get all values in dt2, how will i get all the id's, i tried looping through all the columns but it's the same result i only get the last id in the dt2 table on the first item in the search result while the rest still blank

Comment: You are not looping through the dataset. So it is binding only one row.Also instead of using 2 datasets, inner join the tables and get all values to a single dataset

Comment: even if i do that nothing change, i updated my code.

Comment: Loop dt2 also. Your category and user is in dt2,isn't it?

Comment: i did this and i saw through the debugging that am getting all the values, but there is still the search results, i only get the last record in the loop to be displayed and only on the first item, like in the image above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added one more loop inside for dt2. I am not familiar with vb code. so please check the syntax.

```
For row = 0 To rowcount - 1
    idd = dt1.Rows(row)(0)



    DetailsAdapter2 = New SqlDataAdapter(" select Category.subcategory, Users.username from [Category]  JOIN [LostItem] ON (Category.CategoryID = LostItem.CategoryID) JOIN [Users] ON (LostItem.[User] = Users.[userid] ) WHERE (LostItem.LostId=" & idd & "    ) ", con)
    Dim dt2 As New DataTable

    DetailsAdapter2.Fill(dt2)

 Dim rowcount1 As Integer = dt2.Rows.Count
 For row1 = 0 To rowcount1 - 1


    Dim CategoryLabel As Label = DirectCast(DataList1.Items(0).FindControl("CategoryLabel"), Label)
    CategoryLabel.Text = DirectCast(dt2.Rows(row1)(0), String)
    Dim UserLabel As Label = DirectCast(DataList1.Items(0).FindControl("UserLabel"), Label)
    UserLabel.Text = DirectCast(dt2.Rows(row1)(1), String)
 Next
Next
con.Close()
ResultPanel.Style.Add("display", "block")
```

**OR**

Change query like

```
SELECT CATEGORY.SUBCATEGORY, USERS.USERNAME 
           FROM [CATEGORY]  
           JOIN [LOSTITEM] ON (CATEGORY.CATEGORYID = LOSTITEM.CATEGORYID) 
           JOIN [USERS] ON LOSTITEM.[USER] = USERS.[USERID] 
           WHERE [LOSTITEM].CITY=@CITY AND [LOSTITEM].DATELOST=@DATELOST AND ([LOSTITEM].NAME LIKE '%' + @NAME + '%' OR [LOSTITEM].NAME LIKE '%' + '""' + '%'
```

You will get a new dataset

```
 DataList1.DataSource = dt1
 DataList1.DataBind()
```

In the designer page

```
 <asp:DataList id="DataList1" runat="server">

<HeaderTemplate>
 Your Header
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>

<%#Container.DataItem("subcategory")%> -
$<%#Container.DataItem("username ")%>
 </ItemTemplate>

<FooterTemplate>
Footer comes here
</FooterTemplate>

</asp:DataList>
```

Comment: The syntax is fine, but its still the same issue, the last record is displayed on the first item and the rest are blanks.

Comment: Thanks ALOT, i don't know why i didn't think of using JOIN ♥